# Stopping application from wsadmin takes few mintues

Tags: websphere, jython, build-automation, websphere-8, wsadmin

I am trying to automate deploy process to WebSphere Application Server 8.0.0.4.

Sometimes stopping application is really quick (few seconds), while sometimes it lasts 3-4 minutes and then reports

```
WASX7015E SOAPException: faultCode=SOAP-ENV:Client; 
msg=Read timed out; targetException=java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
```

even though it *successfully* stops the application.

Here is the [log](http://pastebin.com/egMwPSPT). Notice that there is 5 minutes delay from start till the end of operation. Last line is display after above mentioned SOAPException.

This is my code:

```
./wsadmin.sh -lang jython -user user -password password
wsadmin> appmgr = AdminControl.queryNames("*:type=ApplicationManager,*")
wsadmin> AdminControl.invoke(appmgr, 'stopApplication', "myApplication")
```

Comment: I would recommend taking a javacore (`kill -3 PID`) at the time of the delay to determine what the stopApplication thread is doing between WSVR0220I and WSVR0193I.

Answer (score 0):

Update `com.ibm.SOAP.requestTimeout = <some_integer_value>` value in `<WAS_HOME>/profiles/<Deployment_Manager_Profile>/properties/soap.client.props` in order to solve the exception which you are getting. You need to restart the deployment manager in order to solve this issue.

Further more, you can also check [**this**](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/706a5f30-025f-4dc3-b162-01e918fe489e/entry/Application_Edition_Management_and_Automatic_Deployment_with_Ant_Script?lang=en) post to automate your deployment process.

Comment: The property is set to 180 (seconds). Which value would you suggest? I think that maybe it should be set to some lower value so I wouldn't wait so long till exception. But again, there are some operations (e.g. install) which normally last for about 1-2 minutes because app has about 30MB.

Comment: This value signifies the SOAP WebService Timeout.  Increase that value to bigger number. For my instance of WAS i have fixed it to 1800 but it is required as my script is taking that long time to execute. You can try increasing it gradually and fix it accordingly.

Comment: How long does it take when you manually install app through GUI? In my case, it is about 3-4 minutes.

Comment: For me it takes 5 to 6 mins. Try setting the value to 360 and if that doesn't work then increase the number.

Comment: After WAS restart, my script is running as it should.